# Drill down column chart with highcharts4gwt

Tags: gwt, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I want to drill down column chart but using highcharts4Gwt . I am doing

```
Array<Data> data1 = series1.dataAsArrayObject();
            Data dat = highchartsFactory.createSeriesColumnData();
            dat.y(15);
            dat = dat.selected(false);

            Data drillDownSeries = dat.drilldown("drill");
            drillDownSeries.y(5);
            drillDownSeries = drillDownSeries.selected(false);

            data1.setValue(0, dat);
            options.series().addToEnd(series1);
```

but column gets clicked bydefault. I don't want using json , but by the above way with 2 level. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Where you placed your chart? "column gets clicked bydefault" - what column? When chart should be showed?

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle ?